# Python packages installation and import in Azure Automantion Runbook

Tags: python, python-import, azure-keyvault, azure-automation

I install python packages in Azure Automantion Runbook. And after installation I have an issue with import from package azure.keyvault.
Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
import sys


output = subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "azure-identity"], capture_output=True)
print(output)
print('key vault setup')
output = subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "azure-keyvault"], capture_output=True)
print(output)
import site
from importlib import (reload, invalidate_caches)
reload(site)
invalidate_caches()
import azure.identity
import azure.keyvault
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault import secrets
```

Here is the error:

```
Failed
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Temp\oowpjjfq.qph\72071fbe-ccd8-4487-a45f-46c6e9ed9583", line 27, in <module>    from azure.keyvault import secrets Import Error: cannot import name 'secrets' from 'azure.keyvault' (C:\WPy64-3800\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\azure\keyvault\__init__.py)
```

I have no issue with import from azure.keyvault locally. Please also pay attention there is no issue with import azure.keyvault. That's why I think this issue is related to Runbook.
How can I resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

The [azure-keyvault](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault/) package is deprecated and the latest version is just used to install the new set of Azure Key Vault packages:

- [azure-keyvault-certificates](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-certificates/)
- [azure-keyvault-keys](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-keys/)
- [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/)

I'm not entirely sure why the `from azure.keyvault import secrets` line has different behavior locally and in the Runbook -- I can also run that line locally without raising an exception. But to actually work with Azure Key Vault secrets, you'll have to either use the [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/) package or use a legacy version of `azure-keyvault`, such as [version 1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault/1.1.0/).

(I work with the Azure SDK in Python)